# Дерево файлов на PHP

Tags: дерево, php

Такая проблемка: нужно реализовать на сайте дерево файлов и папок. Соответственно вложенные файлы должны отображаться под своей родительской папкой, а файлы без папки (находящиеся в корневом каталоге) просто отображались внизу всех остальных. Имею такой код:

```
function tmlFile($dir){
    $ok = scandir($dir, 0);
        foreach($ok as $k=>$v){
            if($v != '.' && $v != '..'){
                if(is_dir($dir.$v) == true){                                
                    echo 'папка - > <b>'.$dir.$v.'</b><br>';
                    tmlFile($dir.$v.'/');
                }
                elseif(is_file($dir.$v) == true){
                    echo 'файл -> '.$dir.$v.'<br>';
                }
             }                      
         }
}
tmlFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tpl/templates/default/');
```

Выводит почти всё правильно, по крайней мере выводит все папки и все файлы, но в чем ошибка, поймете по картинке:

[image]

Как видите, всё в куче. Красным выделено, соответственно, папка и находящиеся в ней файлы. То, что не выделено, - просто файлы, лежащие в директории (.tpl файлы). Как навести порядок?

Comment: Выводите пути директорий сразу, а файлы складывайте в массив, который выведете после

Comment: @Gedweb, а как быть с файлами в папке? Они не будут выводится, если убрать elseif

Answer (score 1):

В качестве одного из возможно решения будет передача дополнительного параметра `$indent` в рекурсивную функцию `tmlFile()`. На каждой итерации следует увеличивать отступ, таким образом, можно будет выстроить корректное дерево

```
<?php
function tmlFile($dir, $indent = ''){
  $ok = scandir($dir, 0);
  $indent .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;';
  foreach($ok as $k=>$v){
    if($v != '.' && $v != '..'){
      if(is_dir($dir.$v) == true){
        echo $indent.'папка - > <b>'.$dir.$v.'</b><br>';
        tmlFile($dir.$v.'/', $indent);
      }
      elseif(is_file($dir.$v) == true){
        echo $indent.'файл -> '.$dir.$v.'<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}
tmlFile($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/tpl/templates/default/');
```